# Having trouble getting firebase realtime database reference working in Express.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, express, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to do a simple `set()` in my Express.js API. I have followed the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) and set up a config folder with a config file with the following information:

```js
//config_firebase
var firebase = require("firebase");

const config = {
    apiKey: "credentials-go-here",
    authDomain: "credentials-go-here",
    databaseURL: "credentials-go-here",
    projectId: "credentials-go-here",
    storageBucket: "credentials-go-here",
    messagingSenderId: "credentials-go-here",
    appId: "credentials-go-here",
    measurementId: "credentials-go-here"
};

module.exports = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();
```

In this file, is where I try to write to the database using a Firebase reference:

```js
//writeDataService
var app = require("../config/config_firebase");

const writeData = async (uid, userdata) => {
        
        var dbRef2 = app.database()
        
        dbRef2.ref("users/" + uid).child("data").set({
            userdata
        }, function(error){
            if (error){
                //if the write failed
                return(false)
            }
            else {
                //Data saved successfully
                return(true)
            }
        
        });
}

module.exports = {
    writeData
};
```

The code never gets to execute in the `writeDataService` file, meaning that I'm not able to write to the database even though I imported my config file and I get neither a return `false` or `true`. I think there's an error with my config file if anything.  In another service file I initialize the app via `admin`, and here is that code below:

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "credentials-go-here",
        clientEmail: "credentials-go-here",
        privateKey: "credentials-go-here"
    }),
    databaseURL:"credentials-go-here"
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! I feel like I'm overlooking something but I don't know exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to await the dbRef2 action?

```js
const writeData = async (uid, userdata) => {
        
        var dbRef2 = app.database()
        
        await dbRef2.ref("users/" + uid).child("data").set({
            userdata
        }, function(error){
            if (error){
                //if the write failed
                return(false)
            }
            else {
                //Data saved successfully
                return(true)
            }
        
        });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, you could try adding some console logs, and check if the app is initialised, and if the functions are being called. If that's all good, then you can try console logging the refs, it might be that you are not calling `set` on the correct reference.